# Google Fusion Table "Mouseover"

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I was just curious if anyone knew how to implement a "Mouseover" option to a Google Fusion table? Currently, users must click the actual icon rather than hovering over it to see the information box. Any information would be much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Fusion Tables API 1.0 restricts the maximum response size to 10 Mb. We encourage you to migrate to the [Google Fushion Tables API v2.0](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#ftAPI) which provides media download for large payloads.

You can implement `Mouseover` by creating event listener, here's a sample code how to implement mouseover event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', function() {
this.setOptions({fillOpacity: 1});
});
```

For more information regarding Fusion Tables REST API, follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/getting_started#intro). The document includes `migration of v1.0 to v2.0`, `getting started and performance tips`.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for the response but I don't think that solves it. It’s just adding an event listening to a mouseover event. Which is totally fine, but it still can’t pull the data from Google’s servers because they don’t support that. Perhaps there is another solution?